Creating a tree hierarchy for same object using Apex
So I have this requirement for inserting a custom object with self look up. The data will come from CSV file - something like this - The parent to child relation is captured by name
and the name may repeat if not at same level in hiearchy.

As I understand it, I cannot use the external Id as the parent and child object is same -
Save Parent - Child Hierarchy for same SObject in a single DML
As this is going to be a hierarchy, so that means it can multiple levels like 100s of levels so recursion is difficult.
Now other option I can think of is creating a map for records of each level and somehow inserting them level wise. This may get quite complicated to keep a track of all relationships.
So I am reaching out to community now to check if someone has created a multi level parent child relation from a CSV file on same SObject hierarchy.

why not process the CSV file n times until every parent relationship is resolved (i.e., no more work to do in Pass n ?

Is this a one-off migration or something that will be done in a repetitive fashion? I.e. for one-off migration, cropredy's solution is probably most straightforward. But less suited for repetitive process.

Adding details

There are some limitation like same location name can not have same parent and be at same level. So If I insert the location then it may already fail for pass 1. I cannot use external id parent as it is a self look up and salesforce does not allow external d for self look upo


IT can be prepeated process as different countries will try to use the system as and when they can
